# Failed to build gem native extension on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, cmake, devkit

I'm attempting to install the [dandelion](https://github.com/scttnlsn/dandelion) gem on on my Windows machine, but it keeps failing:

```
C:\Users\William>gem install dandelion --platform=ruby
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing dandelion:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150623-7568-1ikffjg.rb extconf.rb
checking for gmake... no
checking for make... yes
checking for cmake... yes
checking for pkg-config... yes
-- cmake .. -DBUILD_CLAR=OFF -DTHREADSAFE=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_C_
FLAGS=-fPIC -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -G "Unix Makefiles"
-- C:\DevKit\bin/make.exe
checking for main() in -lgit2... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=C:/Ruby22/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--use-system-libraries
--with-git2-dir
--without-git2-dir
--with-git2-include
--without-git2-include=${git2-dir}/include
--with-git2-lib
--without-git2-lib=${git2-dir}/lib
--with-git2lib
--without-git2lib
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:735:in `try_func'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:966:in `block in have_library'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:961:in `have_library'
from extconf.rb:89:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rugged-0.2
2.1b1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/rug
ged-0.22.1b1/gem_make.out
```

The error that states "you have to install development tools first" is a head-scratcher. I have already installed DevKit.

Any ideas how to solve this error?

Comment: It also says `Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.`. Read the log files (or at least post them, so we can help you) for more information. But it looks like you're missing libgit2. The `You have to install development tools first.` is a bit confusing but unrelated to the RubyInstaller DevKit.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Here's the logs: http://pastebin.com/17m528Yn

Comment: I should also note that the OpenSSL error is weird. I have that set on the PATH. Not sure what is going on there.

Comment: @WilliamC please avoid excluding crucial elements (like logs) onto external services.

Comment: @Michal Szyndel But I did include my logs...

Comment: @WilliamC ok, so someone must have edited it and moved them to pastebin... :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a fun one. I'm going to take a wild guess and say that you have a version of `libgit2` located in `C:/Program Files (x86)/libgit2/lib` and that folder is somehow in your `Path` or possible some other environment variable.

The fix is to take that folder out of what environment variable that it could be in. That should let `rugged` build correctly.

#### The Problem

When `gcc` is trying to test for the `libgit2` library it sees it could possibly be in `C:/Program Files (x86)/libgit2/lib` and uses `-LC:/Program Files (x86)/libgit2/lib`.

The problem is that it isn't properly escaped, which leads to

```
gcc: error: Files: No such file or directory
gcc: error: (x86)/libgit2/lib: No such file or directory
```

This is actually the same reason why Ruby can't be installed in folders with spaces.

***As a side note:** I'd like to point out that in addition to the regular DevKit you also have `cmake` and `pkg-config` somewhere installed and in your `Path`*

Comment: thanks for the response. You are correct, I do have a copy of libgit2 in my Program Files (x86) directory and it is on my PATH. I'll remove that.

Comment: Also, question about your last comment. Originally, I was getting errors when I had just DevKit installed, so I added cmake and pkg-config. That cleared the error. Should I remove those from my PATH?

Comment: No, those are necessary, I just added that for other people that might stumble across this.

Comment: I removed libgit2 from my path and it still errored out. Here was the error message: http://pastebin.com/KiCwAjNa

Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/dHuLZGDX

Comment: Still looking for it there, look at line #385

Comment: I see. What's weird is my PATH is clear and libgit2 is not in my Program Files (x86) directory any longer. Where else could this be set that I could look for?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. Maybe an `LDFLAGS` environment variable, it might be cached in the `makefile` already, or some other completely different thing. Look through your environment variables closely and try deleting the local files before you try again.